# Синтаксис атрибутов в webBrowser.Anchor

Tags: c#

При изменении ширины webBrowser

```
   webBrowser1.Anchor{Top,Left};
```

Выдает ошибку:

> Ошибка    CS1002  Требуется ";"   Form1.cs    47

Что не так с синтаксисом? Я как только не менял, все равно что-то делаю неправильно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
webBrowser1.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Left;
```

Вероятно, это вам нужно. Побитовое сложение элементов перечисления AnchorStyles.

Кроме того, Anchor - это [свойство](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx), а не [атрибут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/z0w1kczw.aspx).